# How to find the last iteration of a "fgetcsv" while() loop in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop, iteration, fgetcsv

### How to find the last iteration:

Here is an example while loop.  I need to find the last iteration so that a comma will not be added to the end.  How is this done?

```
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
    if (($handle = fopen($files[$i], "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $isfirst = true;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
            if ($isfirst){
                $isfirst = false;
                continue;
        }
            $timestamp = strtotime($data[0].' '.$data[1]);
            fputs($out, '['.(int)$timestamp.','.(float)$data[2].'],');
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

---

### Answer:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
if (($handle = fopen($files[$i], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $isfirst = true;
    $firstline = true;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
        if ($isfirst){
            $isfirst = false;
            continue;
        }
        if ($firstline) {
            $timestamp = strtotime($data[0].' '.$data[1]);
            fputs($out, '['.(int)$timestamp.','.(float)$data[2].']');
            $firstline = false;
        } else {
            $timestamp = strtotime($data[0].' '.$data[1]);
            fputs($out, ',['.(int)$timestamp.','.(float)$data[2].']');
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

}

Comment: Do it the other way round: add a comma at the beginning of every line except the first

Comment: That's a brilliant idea.  But let me update the code(I only included what was needed).  I'm actually not using the first iteration because that is the title.

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
    if (($handle = fopen($files[$i], "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $firstLine = TRUE;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
            if (!$firstLine) {
                fputs($out, ',');
            } else {
                firstLine = FALSE;
            }
            $timestamp = strtotime($data[0].' '.$data[1]);
            fputs($out, '['.(int)$timestamp.','.(float)$data[2].']');
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, actually, I think this will work. Let me plug it in and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Had to edit it slightly, but the idea was in place.  Thanks for your help!